# Taskbar icon will not change once binary is installed

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, wix, icons

I have a WPF application in .net 3.5 sp1 where I change the main window icon periodically. I am seeing the taskbar icon change when running under the vs hosting process, when running directly from the bin/Debug or bin/Release folders, but not when the binary is installed and running from \Program Files! The titlebar icon of the window still changes correctly...

I'm setting the icon like this:

```
Uri imageSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/Images/test.ico");
this.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(imageSource);
```

Why isn't the taskbar icon changing?

I do have an ApplicationIcon set. This is what the taskbar icon is displaying instead of changing to what I set it to. According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.icon.aspx) The ApplicationIcon is just a fallback in case this.Icon is not set.

I do not have the taskbar icon pinned.

The main window is not the startup window of the application. In fact, there is no startup window. The window is opened from a system tray icon.

The icons for the ApplicationIcon and test.ico mentioned above both have their compile action set to Resource.

The WiX installer is not doing anything special to the exe or icons. The exe is referenced like this:

```
<File Id="MyExe" Name="$(var.MyProject.TargetFileName)"
 Source="$(var.MyProject.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes" />
```

I'm currently looking at the [AppUserModelID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378459(VS.85).aspx) to see if this can solve this but it seems unnecessary to override Windows 7's default behavior in this manner. I have two shortcuts created by WiX. One in the start menu's programs folder and one in the start menu's startup folder.

### Update 18Aug11:

Ok this is just odd, odd, odd.

I started trying to solve another annoyance, that my window was allowing taskbar pinning when I don't really want it to (this is default win7 taskbar glomming). So I set IsHostApp REG_BINARY 0000 manually via regedit under HKCR\Applications\MyEXEName.exe. To have the change take effect I had to update the shortcuts that reference the app (or I could have reinstalled). Lo and behold, next time I start up the app, not only does the pinning feature disappear, but the taskbar icon properly updates!!!

Can someone explain how this has solved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Windows Installer creates shortcuts in the Start menu, it sets the icon of the shortcuts which point to Installer cache of icons. This feature is required for advertising, where the referenced file does not exist but still the correct icon should be shown. It also allows showing the correct icon to the application if its main .exe is removed (and you can run MSI repair to fix it).

Your application is started with shortcut from Startup folder, and the icon of the shortcut is used on the Taskbar. (And you have the main window: no matter how you show it, when app starts or only when you click app icon in the notification area; moreover you have to have a window to be able to get clicks from notification area icon.)

When you disabled pinning your app to the Taskbar, it ignores the icon set in the shortcut that started your application, and therefore icon on Taskbar updates when you change the window icon.

Comment: No, you don't need a window to 'get clicks from notification area icon'. My code runs out of an extended Application class and never needs a window open to interact with my tray icon. The taskbar icon is only visible when the main window is open, so I don't see why it's so tightly coupled with the shortcut's icon. After all I have an ApplicationIcon set. But, if I don't hear anything better in 3 days regarding why setting IsHostApp tells Windows to listen to my this.Icon changes, I'll accept this. Thanks for the response!

Comment: What I was trying to say with the "tightly coupled" bit was that it seems strange that the cache is overriding what the application is trying to do with it's icon.

Comment: Oh, also, my feature in msi is set to AllowAdvertise="no", so I don't think these shortcuts are the advertised kind. Testing confirms, self-repair doesn't work if I delete the installdir and run the shortcut. Don't know if that changes anything...

Comment: I didn't say that the window must be visible, but it is required to receive clicks on the notification icon: the window exists even if it is not visible. And Taskbar, of course, does not show buttons for windows that user cannot see.

Comment: It does not matter if the shortcut is advertised or not. What matters is that it has an icon associated with it. Open the shortcut properties and click *Change Icon* button in the properties dialog, and you will see that icon is not taken from the application executable (the target of the shortcut) but rather from the Installer cache. Windows 7 Taskbar displays the icon _associated_ with the shortcut that started the application (to implement pinning, the taskbar also uses shortcuts). To be able to change the taskbar icon dynamically, you have to communicate to taskbar.

Comment: A bit offtopic: changing the icon of the main window does not seem to be a good idea to me. It is harder for users to visually identify your application. What is the purpose of changing the window icon?

Comment: I basically change the color of the background of the icon depending on the state of what the app monitors. Same icon really, just a color change.

Comment: Unless Shell_NotifyIcon() in shell32.dll is creating a hidden window internally, I am not creating any window explicitly in WPF to interact with the tray icon. Communication works just fine. I'm using Hardcodet.NotifyIcon, not System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon, which communicates directly with win32 to manage an icon in the tray ("notification area", I should get used to saying that).

Comment: It's *vice versa*, `Shell_NotifyIcon` *requires* a window handle to be passed. No matter what component or library you use for notification area icon — there must be a window handle, that's how Windows works.

Comment: I finally admit, [Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159%28VS.85%29.aspx) _does_ require a window handle through the NOTIFYICONDATA struct. I missed that. That means the Hardcodet implementation is creating a hidden window internally. Good to know.