# Making shortcut in WPF application corrupts original icon

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, wsh, shortcut-file

So I have a really frustrating problem. I have a WPF application written in C# running Windows 10 (version 1703, OS Build 15063.0) that creates shortcuts for the current running executable. The problem is, when I create these, I set a different (custom) icon for the shortcuts. I didn't think this would be an issue, but the next time I run the application (from the original location) it displays the custom icon which I set for the shortcut in the taskbar. Just the taskbar. The title bar and task manager show the correct icon and title. What am I doing wrong here? At this point I think it's a Windows bug. My method for creating the shortcuts is below:

```
public void CreateShortcut(string name)
{
        string AppDir = GetAppDataDir();
        object shDesktop = (object)"Desktop";
        WshShell shell = new WshShell();
        string shortcutAddress = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\" + name + ".lnk";
        IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
        shortcut.Description = "Play " + name + "!!";
        shortcut.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Shift+N";
        shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        shortcut.TargetPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Catapult.exe";
        shortcut.Arguments = "-play \"" + name + "\"";
        shortcut.IconLocation = AppDir + "/Games/" + name + ".ico";
        shortcut.Save();
}
```

Comment: it will be better if you share some code, and also specify which OS you are using and so on

Comment: The icon show in the titlebar and task manager is provided by the process itself. The icon shown in the taskbar is provided by explorer. When launching a process, there is no predetermined way to override the icon that the process knows about. If you are developer of the process, you can use a command line parameter.

Comment: @JoelLucsy Use a command line parameter for what? Changing the taskbar icon back?

Comment: Now I'm confused. Are you wanting the taskbar to be the icon the program manages itself, or the overriden value you provided in the shortcut? I was assuming the latter. If you want the former, then simple set the icon to the exe when creating the shortcut.

Comment: @JoelLucsy I need the program to show the correct icon (it's own) in the taskbar. This is currently not happening because there is a shortcut referencing the executable with a different icon.

Comment: Then its the shortcut that needs to change.

Comment: @JoelLucsy But I need the shortcut to have a custom icon. Is this impossible?

Comment: Explorer is going to use the icon provided in the shortcut for the icon in the taskbar. You can also see this referenced at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111803/taskbar-icon-will-not-change-once-binary-is-installed

Comment: Only thing you might be able to do is to have the shortcut point to a batch file which launches your program. This will kill the link between whats is run and the shortcut points to.

Comment: @JoelLucsy This was the original design, but it's so much more clunky. This is poor design on Microsoft's part with Explorer. The icon shown in the task bar should be found in the executable, not some shortcut that has the same path. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I guess it is done to account for the fact that a user changing the icon for a shortcut on their desktop would want the task bar icon to match whatever they changed it to.  It's probably written to work from the user's perspective, not the application developer's.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yeah, I suppose. They should still take into account whether the app is being launched directly from the executable or from the customized shortcut though.

Comment: It looks like you can get access to change the icon for the running process via pInvoke. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493442/how-to-change-the-icon-in-taskbar-using-windows-api

Comment: @BradleyUffner That code is for a standard C++ program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that my solution is that there is no solution. In its current state, Windows does **not** allow you to create shortcuts with custom icons that reference an executable **without** messing up the existing icon for that executable. To me, this is unacceptable as I now have to use clunky code to get around this (nothing worse than that, am I right?). Microsoft needs to fix this quirky implementation in Explorer ASAP.

Comment: Have you tried some of the advice [in this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96498/WPF-Integrating-our-application-with-the-Windows-7), does the overlay icon work when launching with a shortcut?

Comment: Nevermind, it did not do what I thought it was going to do.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Haha gotcha, yeah I read it and I was so confused. Thanks anyway.